# Prove Lipschitz function composed with an integrable function is integrable on [a, b]

Tags: real-analysis, integration, function-and-relation-composition

Given a Lipschitz function $g$ (i.e. $|g(x) - g(y)| \leq L |x - y|, \forall x, y \in dom(g)$), and an function $f$ integrable on $[a, b]$, how do we prove $g \circ f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$, preferably using Darboux integrals/sums?

Let us assume $g, f$ have appropriate domains and codomains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $M=\sup_{x \in [a,b]} f(x), m = \inf_{x \in [a,b] } f(x)$, then
\begin{eqnarray}
\sup_{x \in [a,b]} g(x) -\inf_{x \in [a,b] } g(x) &=& \sup_{x,y\in [a,b]}
g(x)-g(y) \\
&=& \sup_{x,y\in [a,b]} |g(x)-g(y)|  \\
&\le & L \sup_{x,y\in [a,b]} |f(x)-f(y)| \\
&\le & L \sup_{x,y\in [a,b]} f(x)-f(y) \\
&=& L (M-m)
\end{eqnarray}

Now consider a partition $P$ such that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < { \epsilon \over L}$
and use the above to estimate $U(g\circ f,P) - L(g \circ f,P)$.

Comment: Hey @copper.hat. Why does the second equality hold? (What if sup(g(x) - g(y)) is negative?) Additionally, why does the second inequality hold? (These two might be the same question.)

Comment: $\sup_{x,y} (g(x)-g(y))$ cannot be negative as $g(x)-g(x) = 0$ hence the $\sup$ must be $\ge 0$. Since $g(x)-g(y) \le |g(x)-g(y)|$, one direction is straightforward. If $g(x) \ge g(y)$, we always have either $g(x)-g(y) = |g(x)-g(y)|$ or $g(x)-g(y) = |g(y)-g(x)|$, hence the other direction follows too.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: A function is (Riemann) integrable if and only if its set of discontinuity has measure zero.

Comment: Thanks, @Sam, although this is in the context of an elementary real analysis course, where measure is not covered.