# Prove that $g^+= max(0,g(x))$ is integrable on $I$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $I$ be a bounded and closed rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^3$. $g$ is integrable function on $I$.

Prove that $g^+= max(0,g(x))$ is integrable on $I$ and $|g|$ are integrable on $I$.

Comment: What is the point in mentioning $f$ if you never mention it later?

Comment: this is the fifth part of the question, which is where I am stuck on. will correct it now.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/796797/27978

Comment: is that a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Divide $I$ into two regions: $I = I_+ \cup I_{-}$, where

$$I_+ = \{x \in I ~|~ g(x) \geq 0\} ~~~ \mathrm{and} ~~~ I_{-} = \{x \in I ~|~ g(x)<0\}$$

Since $g$ is integrable on $I$, it is integrable on both $I_+$ and $I_{-}$. And you can see that $\int_I g^+ \, dx = \int_{I_+} g \, dx$, because $g^+ = 0$ on $I_{-}$.

Also, $|g| = g^+ + (-g)^+$, so the fact that $|g|$ is integrable follows from above.

Comment: That is a bit glib for a Riemann integral. How do you know that $g \cdot 1_{I_+}$ is integrable?

Comment: You're right. I was being a bit loose and careless. There probably need to be more assumptions for what I said to work. Should I delete my answer?